# AWS DataZone - CloudFormation Templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-datazone

I started working with AWS DataZone as it is now GA. AWS CLI already supports it (https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/datazone/index.html). But I can't find the template specification (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-reference.html).

Does it already exist?
If yes, where can I find it?
If not, when will it be available?